# how to configure Eglot over TRAMP?

Tags: tramp, lsp, eglot, python-lsp-server

On my laptop, I'm using `eglot` (sometimes `lsp-mode`) with `pyright` language server.

But Now I'm trying to write some python code on Raspberry Pi (using `ssh`/`TRAMP`, in local network, from my laptop). I currently installed `pyright` with `pip3 install pyright` on RPi, and when `M-x eglot` executed on `tramp` buffer it says:

```
[eglot] Sorry, couldn't guess for `python-mode'!
Enter program to execute (or <host>:<port>):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eglot` doesn't need any special config to work with `tramp`. You need to make `tramp` can find your remote `pyright`, maybe via:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path 'tramp-own-remote-path)
```

For `lsp-mode`, you can refer to this [PR](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/pull/2531).